# Why am I getting the Error: unexpected type required: variable found: value

Tags: java, arrays, dynamic

I am trying to create a shuffle class for the cards dynamic array
I the cards array contains strings for suit and rank and int for value

here is where im getting the error required: variable   found:    value

```
private void Shuffle() { 
    for (int p  = 0; p <1000; p++) {
        int rand1 = (int) (Math.random()* 52);
        int rand2 = (int) (Math.random()*52);
        Card Temp = cards.get(rand1);
        cards.get(rand1) = cards.get(rand2);
        cards.get(rand2) = Temp;
    }
}
```

Comment: "Here" is a bit vague. But you're trying to set a value on a function call; it's more likely you want to be swapping two cards in the cards... array? List? Unrelated, but it's best to follow Java naming conventions to help keep code clear.

Comment: The problem with the question is that it's not complete. As others have pointed out, we are missing the information what type/class 'cards' actually is. PLUS consider not to use Magic Numbers, ESPECIALLY the 52 in the code will sooner or later become a problem. Use `cards.size()` or comparable counter to be safe. If you have less than 52 cards, the code will crash, if you have more, cards 52 and up (because int-casts always round towards zero amd Math.random never becomes 1) will never be shuffled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you are trying to shuffle cards 1000 times randomly, soo the most simplistic approach IMHO would be something like this (assuming your cards are in ArrayList)

```java
private void Shuffle() {
    for (int p = 0; p < 1000; p++) {
        int rand1 = (int) (Math.random() * 52);
        int rand2 = (int) (Math.random() * 52);
        Card card1 = cards.get(rand1);
        Card card2 = cards.get(rand2);
        cards.set(rand1, card2);
        cards.set(rand2, card1);
    }
}
```

Comment: You assume 52 to be the deck size. You should rather use `cards.size()` instead, not to run into weird problems.

Answer (score 1):

I believe, cards is of type List. cards.get(index) returns an object of the Card. An object can be assigned to a reference and not to another object.
Hence, cards.get(rand1) = cards.get(rand2) is like assigning an object to another object. It is similar to writing 1=2.